# I want to place an image on top of an iframe that has links and js running?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, z-index

I want to place an image on top of a logo of a company that is there but when i use z-index, the background page doesn't work. [Here is a link to an example.](http://static.fliphtml5.com/web/demo/manual/index.html) I want to replace the company logo but still have the page functional.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Is this do it for me stuff? or have you tried it before.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're wanting to take another person's work and make it look as if it's your own by pulling their page into yours with an iframe and hiding their logo behind yours. Is this correct? If so it is wholly unethical if not illegal. And even if it could be done. It shouldn't. Do your own work instead!